# Count the total views of all user posts published

Tags: posts, comments, count, views

I have 1 essential questions

I want to count the total views of all posts published by a user (login user).

### for example show:

total view of your all posts: 485

---

Is there a way to do this?
Can you help me?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. But, please, focus on one question only. [How to ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes that's right . I corrected my question